# using apache oozie ssh actions to execute spark-submit, why does the spark application is stuck on state accepted

Tags: ssh, apache-spark, oozie

I am trying to run several spark applications one after one and scheduling them using oozie. I used an ssh action, that should run spark-submit on my spark application. 
When simple running the spark application from the server the application starts running, however, when i used the oozie ssh action to run the spark-submit, i could see a new spark application appeared, but the state of the application is stuck on "ACCEPTED" and never actually starts running.

My ssh action looks like that :

```
<host> ${user}@${host}</host>
<command>spark-submit</command>
<args>--driver-memory</args>
<args>6G</args>
<args>--deploy-mode</args>
<args>cluster</args>
<args>--class</args>
<args>main.Application</args>
<args>--executor-memory</args>
<args>6G</args>
<args>--master</args>
<args>yarn-cluster</args>
<args>duplicate.jar</args>
... [the jar's arguments]
<capture-output />
```

Am I using the oozie ssh action correctly?

Has anyone tried doing what I'm trying to do?

Does anybody have an idea why the application never starts running?