# launching a spark program using oozie workflow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, workflow, oozie

I am working with a scala program using spark packages.
Currently I run the program using the bash command from the gateway:
/homes/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --class "com.xxx.yyy.zzz" --driver-java-options "-Dyyy.num=5" a.jar arg1 arg2

I would like to start using oozie for running this job. I have a few setbacks:

Where should I put the spark-submit executable? on the hfs?
How do I define the spark action? where should the --driver-java-options appear?
How should the oozie action look like? is it similar to the one appearing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098841/using-apache-oozie-ssh-actions-to-execute-spark-submit-why-does-the-spark-appli%20)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a new enough version of  oozie you can use oozie's spark task:

https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/client/src/main/resources/spark-action-0.1.xsd

Otherwise you need to execute a java task that will call spark. Something like:

```
   <java>
        <main-class>org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit</main-class>

        <arg>--class</arg>
        <arg>${spark_main_class}</arg> -> this is the class com.xxx.yyy.zzz

        <arg>--deploy-mode</arg>
        <arg>cluster</arg>

        <arg>--master</arg>
        <arg>yarn</arg>

        <arg>--queue</arg>
        <arg>${queue_name}</arg> -> depends on your oozie config

        <arg>--num-executors</arg>
        <arg>${spark_num_executors}</arg>

        <arg>--executor-cores</arg>
        <arg>${spark_executor_cores}</arg>

        <arg>${spark_app_file}</arg> -> jar that contains your spark job, written in scala

        <arg>${input}</arg> -> some arg 
        <arg>${output}</arg>-> some other arg

        <file>${spark_app_file}</file>

        <file>${name_node}/user/spark/share/lib/spark-assembly.jar</file>
    </java>
```

Comment: Another option is to launch a shell action. Do you have any reasons why a Java action should be preferred?

Comment: better: Spark Action > Java Action > Shell Action. Because you don't know which node the shell is running on, then you need to guarantee that all nodes should have the dependencies for the shell script

Comment: The spark-assembly.jar is no longer valid starting on Spark v2.0.0 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11157